# pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure - Restarting apache2

Tags: server, apache2, django

I am deploying my website on a Linux Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 19) on Linode.

My deployment worked when allowed: xx.xx.xx.xx:8000

To allow HTTP/TCP traffic I did:

```
sudo delete allow 8000
sudo allow http/tcp
```

When I run:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I get:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So if I run:

```
journalctl -xe
```

I get:

```
Aug 28 18:52:06 django-server sudo[14724]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=ucluser uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser=ucluser rhost=  user=ucluser
Aug 28 18:52:30 django-server sshd[14529]: Received disconnect from 109.175.190.135 port 50098:11: disconnected by user
Aug 28 18:52:30 django-server sshd[14529]: Disconnected from user ucluser 109.175.190.135 port 50098
Aug 28 18:56:49 django-server sshd[14705]: Received disconnect from 109.175.190.135 port 50197:11: disconnected by user
Aug 28 18:56:49 django-server sshd[14705]: Disconnected from user ucluser 109.175.190.135 port 50197
Aug 28 19:27:40 django-server sshd[17050]: Received disconnect from 109.175.190.135 port 50366:11: disconnected by user
Aug 28 19:27:40 django-server sshd[17050]: Disconnected from user ucluser 109.175.190.135 port 50366
```

I think the problem is here:

```
**Aug 28 18:52:06 django-server sudo[14724]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=ucluser uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser=ucluser rhost=  user=ucluser**
```

But I am not sure how to solve it

If I run:

```
apachectl stop
```

I get:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 50 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/django_project.conf: Expected </Directory> but saw </VirtualHost>
Action 'stop' failed.
```

Comment: What is Linux 19?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Ubuntu version 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

In my `django_project.conf` I forgot to close a `</Directory>`.

From

```
<Directory>
    Something written here
<Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory>
    Something written here
</Directory>
```

The closing slash `/` was missing